Меньше кода, проще код
$ratio = 
     ($f = simplexml_load_file('/manifest.mpd', "SimpleXMLElement", LIBXML_NOERROR |  LIBXML_ERR_NONE)->Period->AdaptationSet[0])
     ? $f['maxWidth'].'/'.$f['maxHeight'] : null;

Любопытно, подобного рода код, условие. Возможно проще писать, короче строчку сделать и тп?
$ratio = ($f = simplexml_load_file('/manifest.mpd', "SimpleXMLElement", LIBXML_NOERROR |  LIBXML_ERR_NONE)->Period->AdaptationSet[0])
['maxWidth'].'/'.$f['maxHeight'];


А этот код у вас что. рабочий? Судя по синтаксису должна вылетать ошибка, поскольку  ($f = ...) это не условие. Не говоря о том, что дальше ещё хуже...

Основные ошибки скрыты, когда переменная заведомо не объявлено и он в html документе. Использую php8, не знаю как на других версиях. Никакой ошибки нет, так я сразу и условие делаю на наличие данных и эти самые данные вношу в переменную и туже по результатам достаю уже в условии. Минимализ,

Добавил еще вариант, но уже без условия.

Во-первых, если вы хотите получить корректный ответ на ваш вопрос, то лучше воспользоваться правилом хорошего тона и дать возможность воспроизвести проблему. Не обязательно тащить simplexml_load_file, если его можно заменить близкой переменной. Во-вторых, и собственно отвечая на ваш вопрос,... что первый пример, что второй — нечитабельны, не для легкого восприятия. Через год вы сами глядя на это десять раз споткнётесь глазом о синтаксис.  Хотите упростить? Создайте переменную с результатом simplexml_load_file и уж потом упрощайте.

Меньше кода, не всегда, проще код

Для справки: `Внимание
Функция возвращает как логическое значение false, так и нелогическое значение, которое приводится к false. Прочитайте раздел «Логический тип», чтобы получить дополнительную информацию. Используйте оператор === для проверки значения, которое возвращает функция.` из документации...

Меньше на что и на сколько? Меньше строк? Это
$ratio = ($f = simplexml_load_file('/manifest.mpd', "SimpleXMLElement", LIBXML_NOERROR |  LIBXML_ERR_NONE)->Period->AdaptationSet[0]) ? $f['maxWidth'].'/'.$f['maxHeight'] : null;

против этого
$f = simplexml_load_file('/manifest.mpd', "SimpleXMLElement", LIBXML_NOERROR |  LIBXML_ERR_NONE)->Period->AdaptationSet[0];
$ratio = ($f) ? $f['maxWidth'].'/'.$f['maxHeight'] : null;

И даже если первый пример разбить на строки, то читабельнее он не станет.

AdaptationSet[0]) - лишняя скобка )

Спасибо, недосмотрел, поправил. Была у меня мысль о том, чтобы объяснить, что и эту строку следует разобрать на куски, отделив  ->Period->AdaptationSet[0] и перенести ниже и почему ему не место в первой строке, но решил не мешать "минимизации". Когда-нибудь и сам поймёт столкнувшись.)
